# Describing a typeclass for general graphs in Haskell

Tags: haskell, graph, polymorphism, typeclass, type-theory

I'm trying to write a typeclass for graphs. Basically, the typeclass looks like:

```
class Graph g where
  adjacentNodes :: g n -> n -> [n]
```

in which I use `n` to represent the type of nodes.

Then I have the following `Graph` defined like this:

```
data FiniteGraph n = FiniteGraph { runFiniteGraph :: Array n [n] }
```

where `Array` is adopted from the standard container `Data.Array`, the structure is to represent a finite graph in the way to map each node to their adjacent nodes.

Here comes the problem, when I try to make `FiniteGraph` an instance of `Graph`.

```
instance Graph FiniteGraph where
  adjacentNodes g n = (runFiniteGraph g) ! n
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work, because the `!` operator requires the constraint `Ix n`, but I find no where to declare it.

I expect the instance declaration to be some like:

```
instance (Ix n) => Graph (FiniteGraph n) where { ... }
```

But this requires the `g` in `class Graph g` to have the kind `*` instead of `* -> *`, such that I would have no where to show that `n` depend on `g`.

So what can I do with that? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be done after you add a second param to the `Graph` class.

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
import Data.Array

class Graph g n | n -> g where
  adjacentNodes :: g n -> n -> [n]

data FiniteGraph n = FiniteGraph { runFiniteGraph :: Array n [n] }

instance Ix n => Graph FiniteGraph n where
  adjacentNodes g n = (runFiniteGraph g) ! n
```

That makes sense if you think about it: graph requires the notion of a vertex.

Comment: How about turning the functional dependency around: `g -> n`? That way you could have different graphs (e.g. edge list, adjacency matrix) with the same node type (e.g. `Int`).

Comment: Removing the functional dependency would be sufficient to achieve this.